# "subversion"-like setup on Windows 7

Tags: windows, svn, backup

I need a software which can save all the previous versions of a file, with some kind of "auto commit". I don't want to use a remote server like github etc.

I am one of those noob programmers, who try to do everything by trial and error. But, sometimes, a change in the source code screws up things even more and I need to go back to an older version of the source. Today was even worse. My hard worked code got filled up completely with null bytes after a power faliure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the question. Install SVN (or another SCM).

And at least eclipse has a local history, in case you need to go back to something you haven't committed. Don't know about other IDEs.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention that im working in eclipse. the local history feature is awesome! this ans. helped me

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of version control systems that work locally.  Git, for instance, is entirely self-contained; you have the ability to push your history to a remote server, but there's no requirement to do so.  The same goes for Mercurial.  Even Subversion and CVS let you use a local, file-based repo, though with them you have an extra step of creating that repo in a separate location from your working directory.

Kicking it really old-school, RCS and SCCS have no concept of a server at all. :)

I'm not sure what OP's objection is to a server-based SCM system; remote backups are a good thing, and you can get them for free.  But most SCM systems work fine wholly contained on a single box.

As far as the "automatic" commits go, you can probably configure your IDE to commit every time you save.  Which seems more useful than something outside of the IDE automatically saving the file every N minutes or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a remote server. Just use a decent SCM. Subversion is probably not your best bet, as it requires you to set up a repository outside your working copy, which can be inconvenient. On top of that, a few bad design decisions were made in its development, and this can lead to frustrating and confusing situations.

Assuming that you are on windows, I would recommend **mercurial** - it is straightforward, self-contained, easy to learn, cross-platform, and free (in both senses). Basically, what it does is create a hidden directory named `.hg` inside your project's root directory, where it keeps a full history of your project. You do have to actively tell it when to make snapshots though, but this is really simple and straightforward. Check out http://hginit.com/ for a no-nonsense introduction.

The other alternative is **git**; it's more versatile than mercurial and slightly faster, but the windows port is a bit of an orphaned child, and its community is less noob-friendly.

Comment: I like Mercurial too but it's worth knowing that github have released a nice [Windows client](http://windows.github.com/). It doesn't need a github account as it will work with any git server as well as local repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would certainly recommend using a "normal" SCM, but since you're against that, how about just plain old windows backup?  If you use BitBucket, you can choose mercurial which is a distributed system, keeping a local only copy of the repo until you push it.

Another option is to use a command line script to commit to a SCM, such as SVN or Mercurial every X minutes.

Mercurial/BitBucket command:

```
hg commit -m "Auto Committed"
```

Stick that in a batch file and use scheduler to run it on an interval.

Don't fight the tools...

Comment: OP said they don't want to use a remote server, so bitbucket is out.  No reason they can't use hg or git locally, though.

Answer (score 0):

When I started programming and wanted a similar thing I just used Dropbox on my computer, and put my project folder in my Dropbox. Every time you save a file in your dropbox it is automaticly sent to the server and you are able to view each save on the site and download/revert to previous versions. Simple, easy, you dont need to worry about all the extra features of a source control system, and if your a student it makes it easy to work on your stuff at school where they dont have SVN on their computers.